I'm trying to create an Image gallery as a blocklist Item in Umbraco 13
Hi I have the code that works for a single image but I'm stuck on modifying the code for the multiple image picker.  This is what I've tried but it gives me a blank page.
t@inherits UmbracoViewPage<BlockListItem>

@{
    var row = (GalleryRow)Model.Content;
    if (row.GalleryImages==null) return;
    
}

 <div class="container col-12 pb-3">  
<div class="row">


<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
@{
    var row.GalleryImages = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("GalleryImages");
    foreach (var item in row.GalleryItems)
    {
        <img src="@item.Url" style="width:200px"/>
    }
}
  
 </div>    

</div></div>

Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried the above I would like the user to select Gallery block select upto 10 images and for the images to display on the page with the rest of the bloacklist items.

Here's the correct code should anyone need it:
    @using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Models.PublishedContent
    @inherits UmbracoViewPage<BlockListItem>
    
    @{
        var row = (GalleryRow)Model.Content;
        if (row.GalleryImages==null) return;        
    }
    
    <div class="container col-12 pb-3">  
    <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    @{var _mediaFolder = Umbraco.MediaAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf<Folder>().First();    }
                            @if (_mediaFolder != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var image in _mediaFolder.Children)
                                {
                                    //make sure it isn't another folder
                                    if (image.Children != null && !image.Children.Any())
                                    {
                                                <img src="@image.Url()" class="example-image img-responsive" >
                                    }
                                }
                            }
    
    </div>    
    
    </div>
    </div>


Remove this line because you are overwriting the values of row.GalleryImages.
var row.GalleryImages = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("GalleryImages");

